# How to add tab space infront of mutiple lines of code

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, text-editor, documentation-generation

I am using eclipse IDE for development I have written some code in if-else block and now I want to tab indent every block, Is there any way or command or key sequence so that I can select the lines of code and simply add tab space in front of every line selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formatter for this. Right click your file and select `Source` -> `Format`. You can also execute this for a single code block. Just select the block and right click -> `Source` -> `Format`. You can also format Javadoc this way.

If you don't like the way your code gets formatted you can change the formatter template in `Windows` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Code` -> `Formatter`.

Answer (score 0):

Select the block(or set of statements) and just press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to indent. The whole selected block(or set of statements) will be moved.